# port 41826 unknown on home router ip 192.168.1.8 why is the port open?

Tags: router, port

Using Port Droid, I scanned all ports for IPv4 on my home router. I found port 41826 unknown on home router ip 192.168.1.8 open unknown. Why is the port open or unknown? Port forwarding is closed. I don't have anything open on my end. Netstat doesn't show that port at all.

Google search shows various brothers in arms games use it. I am not a gamer and don't have brothers in arms. I don't have any ports forwarding. It also shows spyse.com as using that port. I can't surf to Spyse.com. I get a 501 error server is down.

What should all this tell me about any risks I have or don't have from port 41826 unknown on IP 192.168.1.8?

Comment: Your post is unclear. If you have scanned from the internet, where from did you get the address of `192.168.1.8` or `spyse.com`? These cannot be seen from the internet.

Comment: Do you have UPnP enabled on the router _(if so, it should be disabled and ports manually forwarded)_? There's only two ways WAN facing ports on a router can be opened, manually configuring port forward rules or UPnP, which should never be enabled because it's a security risk and there is no secure implementation of UPnP.

Comment: The port is listed as `unknown` because there is no [IANA assignment](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) for it. Are you sure you're looking at your router? Your router could technically use 192.168.1.8, but it's very unlikely. Router IPs are usually the first or last host address in a subnet (`.1` or `.254`).

Comment: I scanned my public IP from the internet using Port Droid. Port Droid shows scan results and additional information. It showed port 41826 as open. It displayed an IP address on the LAN side of my network, 192.168.1.8, next to the port #. I Googled to see what services use port 41826. Those services include Spyse.com, a search engine for pen testers. Other services that use that port include Brothers in Arms games. I don't have Universal Plug and Play enabled. I don't have port forwarding enabled. My router does not use 192.168.1.8. That is an IP on my internal network.

Comment: In the meantime, I used an online port scanner to check the port, and it assessed the port as being stealthed.